# How to batch rotate image to make them all landscape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, workflow, photoshop-scripting, batch-processing, rotate

I have a thousand of pictures of the same fixed scene, but for an unknown reason some of them are vertical, not horizontal.

So I would like to batch process all the images and rotate them 90° if the width is smaller than the height of the image.

I tried to play with the "Action" and the "Batch process" feature, but I did not find where I can add conditional to my scripts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is possible. Someone else will post the answer, but I'm thinking there is a more hands-on way to do it. In a folder (in Windows but probably also on Mac) you could sort images by their dimensions, then move the vertical images to another folder, perform the rotate batching and move the files back.

Comment: In Windows you can even just select the vertical files, right-click and rotate them directly in the folder. (I understand why you probably still want a proper answer on how to automate this in Photoshop)

Comment: @Wolff, nice way of doing it I did not know that !

Comment: I'm unsure if using Windows to rotate images affects JPG image quality...

Comment: @Wolff Yes, it does in some cases - AFAIR it's when height or width can't be divided by 8. Also it tends to rewrite some metadata. I can't tell exactly what, but I remember creating tool for translating "Windows-cured" metadata.

Comment: Hm ages ago I did similar with Paintshop Pro - which has a macro-language similar to VBA build in. Load image - test size and aspect-ratio ... resize - save with slightly altered name (aka +" resize") .. rinse repeat ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put a Conditional step in an action: use the `Insert Conditional...` command in the Actions flyout menu:

[image]

So first create an action to rotate and save a document. Then create an action with a condition. There's a rule `If Current Document Is Landscape`

[image]

so `Then Play Action` will remain `None` and `Else Play Action` will be your rotate & save action.

Answer (score 8):

Easier solution:

- Use Bridge, which has a filter for orientation.
- Drop the images into a folder, click the 'portrait' filter, which selects every portrait image in your folder, then the rotate tool at the top.
- Done.

[image]